# Why does this question have a giant bolded section?

Tags: support, markdown-rendering

I intended to edit this question: [Sorting an array on more than one criterion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28571384/array-sorting-java) but when I clicked Edit I was presented with

[image]

and no option to see the markdown or HTML to adjust the large bold font which has been used.

Is this an improvement which I do not understand?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The horizontal line of dashes `------------` assumes that the text above it is a `<h2>` style heading. If you want a horizontal line you should add a line break before and after it.

See the [editing help](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help) section about headings.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know *why* this causes the giant bold block, but the

---

Below the paragraph is doing it. If you add a new line, it works as expected. For example:

### Bold text

So no, editing isn't borked, its just that the thing *causing* the bold isn't obvious/expected.

Answer (score 1):

That's a [Markdown heading](http://daringfireball.net/projects/markdown/syntax#header) (H2 -> equivalent to `## Heading`).

You can create a heading

### Like this

### Or like this

<sub>See [source](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/revisions/6e352d12-29a7-445c-89c2-f70958945ae0/view-source).</sub>

Essentially, whenever you use break notation (`---`) without an empty line above it, whatever *is* in the line above it turns into a heading. This is intended to be an intuitive way to separate sections.